# How to get Cookies already set on the browser

Tags: magento2, php-5.4, cookie

I have cookies already set on the browser, name as **cookie_name**. And how can I use magento 2 cookies manager. to retrieve the cookie already set on the browser.

```
<?php

 namespace YourCompany\Module\Plugin;

 use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class CartPlugin
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
 */
protected $quote;

protected $request;
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
*/
protected $_cookieManager;
/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
*/
 static protected $_key = null;
/**
 * Plugin constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request, 
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
) {
    $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $this->request = $request;        
}

/**
 * beforeAddProduct
 *
 * @param      $subject
 * @param      $productInfo
 * @param null $requestInfo
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */

 public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{        
    $cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie('cookie_name');
    var_dump($cookieValue);
    die();
    return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
}
```

The  result on browser is given me **NULL**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the below code to get cookie.

```
<?php

namespace Training\Rememberme\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;


class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * Name of Cookie that holds private content version
     */
    CONST COOKIE_NAME = 'remember';

    /**
     * Cookie life time
     */
    CONST COOKIE_LIFE = 604800;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
     */
    protected $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var $scopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfigInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $sessionManager;


    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigInterface,
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    ){
        $this->scopeConfigInterface = $scopeConfigInterface;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get data from cookie set in remote address
     *
     * @return value
     */
    public function getCookie($name)
    {
        return $this->cookieManager->getCookie($name);
    }

    /**
     * Set data to cookie in remote address
     *
     * @param [string] $value    [value of cookie]
     * @param integer $duration [duration for cookie] 7 Days
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCookie($value, $duration = 604800)
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration($duration)
            ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $value, $metadata);

    }

    /**
     * delete cookie remote address
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function delete($name)
    {
        $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie(
            $name,
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory
                ->createCookieMetadata()
                ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
                ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain())
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return var
     */
    public function getCookielifetime()
    {
        return self::COOKIE_LIFE;
    }
}
```

Call the Helper in your file like

> $_helper = $this->helper('Training\Rememberme\Helper\Data');

Then call the function like below.

> $_helper->getCookie('cookiename');

Comment: Still give me null

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I delete. I'm sure you can modify to get.

```
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    $cookieMetadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory->createCookieMetadata()->setPath('/');
    $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie('you-cookie-name', $cookieMetadata);
}
```

Comment: What is the use of  "->setPath('/')"